# PHP/mysql ignores record which have Asterix character

Tags: php, mysql

I used the following code to add record into from one *MySQl* table to another it works for all Company Name except for the ones with `*` for example tried to add `Customer_Bill_name=XXX CO., LLC* "` skips adding in to the table. how can i handle this issue?

I used the following code. Please help

```
'CUSTOMER' => htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name'], ENT_QUOTES),
```

Thanks!

Comment: There’s not enough context to help you here. You posted a part of an associative array, but never explained what this associative array was, where it was used, what it was used for, etc.

Comment: Thanks @icktoofay 'CUSTOMER' field is Linked field the values in this field comes from another table in order to add `Customer_Bill_name` to this field you need to have the exact matching record that means 'CUSTOMER' must be exactly equal to the value of 'Customer_Bill_Name'. but bc of `*` i am not able to add record

Comment: @icktoofay Also i have the matching record on both side XXX CO., LLC* =XXX CO., LLC*

Comment: [Asterix character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name'])
```

It may help you.

Comment: Is it safe to remove that * from record. If it is allowed than use 
    str_replace('*', '', $tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name'])