# Trackvia ignores records containing apostrophes

Tags: php

Both

```
'CUSTOMER' => htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name'], ENT_QUOTES)
```

and

```
 'CUSTOMER' => mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name']),
```

are not able to solve my issue escaping `'` apostrophes

I have 'CUSTOMER' field which is a `linked field(dropdown list)` which means the values in this field comes from another table. Inorder to add/Select  `Customer_Bill_name` equivalent from this field you need to have the exact matching record that means `CUSTOMER` must be exactly equal to the value of `Customer_Bill_Name`.

But I am having a problem when the `Customer_Bill_Name` contains `'` apostrophes forexample `XXX'S LLC`.

i tried `var_dump()`, `print_r()` to see how the data looks like, but i cant see any problem the problem is when try to enter record it doesn't, I tried to send an array with out `Customer_Bill_name` works fine.

$records

```
     $records=array(
      'CUSTOMER' => mysql_escape_string($tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name']),
      'WHEEL PN 1-S' => htmlspecialchars($wheelpn, ENT_QUOTES),
      'QUANTITY'          => htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['Quantity'], ENT_QUOTES),
      'SO DATE'          =>htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['TransactionDate'], ENT_QUOTES),
      'SO NUMBER'         => htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['Reference'], ENT_QUOTES),
       'CUSTOMER PN' => htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['PartNumber'], ENT_QUOTES),

      'SHIP VIA'         => htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['WhichShipVia'], ENT_QUOTES),
      'PROMISED DATE'         => htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['ShipByDate'], ENT_QUOTES),
      'COMMENTS'         => htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['Comment'], ENT_QUOTES),
      'PO #'         => htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['CustomerInvoiceNo'], ENT_QUOTES),   
      'WO Notes'         =>htmlspecialchars($tmpArray['SalesDescription'], ENT_QUOTES),
      'ROUTING'         =>htmlspecialchars($routing, ENT_QUOTES),


   );

$tv->addRecord($tableId, $records);
```

//addRecord() function

```
  /**
 * Add more than one record at once to a table. Batch inserts.
 * 
 * @param  int   $tableId
 * @param  array $records
 * @return array
 */
 public function addRecords($tableId, $records)
   {
     $url = self::BASE_URL . self::RECORDS_URL;
     $data = array(
     'table_id' => $tableId,
     'records' => $records
    );
    return $this->api($url, 'POST', json_encode($data), 'json');
    }
```

`var_dump($tableId)`, `var_dump($records)`, `var_dump($this->api(...))`:

```
    int(45454270957) array(12) { 
             ["CUSTOMER"]=> NULL 
             ["WHEEL PN 1-S"]=> string(0) "" 
             ["QUANTITY"]=> string(21) "2.0000000000000000000" 
             ["SO DATE"]=> string(10) "2010-12-02" 
             ["SO NUMBER"]=> string(5) "655028" 
             ["CUSTOMER PN"]=> string(0) "" 
             ["SHIP VIA"]=> string(3) "DHL" 
             ["PROMISED DATE"]=> string(10) "2014-12-23" 
             ["COMMENTS"]=> string(0) "" 
             ["PO #"]=> string(4) "98430" 
             ["WO Notes"]=> string(16) "sps990X15 8-8 JDY" 
             ["ROUTING"]=> string(0) "" } NULL
```

Please help Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [php ignores records contains apostrophes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370696/php-ignores-records-contains-apostrophes)

Comment: @Dagon OP deleted it off the map.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well you and i can still read it - guess he will get all the same answers *agan*, sure that will be a lot of help

Comment: @Hulu your basic approach (mysqli_real_escape_string) seems fine, the fact that it does not work leads me to suspect something else is happening, you need to provide the full code your using with an example.

Comment: @Dagon Yeah, OP's going to have to provide more code.

Comment: Then there's http://stackoverflow.com/q/27339516/ @Dagon who was given bad advice `mysqli_real_escape_string($tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name'])`

Comment: Hulu; are you using `mysql_` or `mysqli_` or PDO to connect? You have `mysql_escape_string` then you say you tried `mysqli_escape_string` - Two different animals altogether. So, what's your APIs flavour?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Appologise about my mistake, but it wasnt intentional, I am not here to waste your time

Comment: hulu we are tying but need your assistance, we need more than one line of code

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am using `mysqli_`, thanks

Comment: ok you say **mysqli_** but your code uses *mysql_escape_string* **i** or not to **i** that is the question

Comment: and its really unlikely that `htmlspecialchars()` around everything is a good idea

Comment: what framework is that?

Comment: Apparently [we have to play detective around here and read minds](https://github.com/Trackvia/Classic-API-php-Library/blob/master/Trackvia/Api.php)

Comment: @sjagr No need to read mind i am using their product (TRACKVIA APP and TRYING to SYNC DESKTOP APP) and try to synchronize desktop application with trackvia Clousd applicattion, i am almost there except these issue for some company name. Please be posetive.

Comment: Yes, we can see that _now_, but since you haven't provided code that gave me just a hint of what you were using until just now, you have literally wasted others days leaving us in the dark about a dependent library that revolves around your entire question. It's no wonder no one was able to help you. And for that matter, the newest commit in that library is 2 years old - I wonder if Trackvia has changed their API since then.

Comment: I'd recommend that you [switch to this updated library](https://github.com/Trackvia/API-PHP-SDK) - the one you're using looks like it has been intentionally deprecated.

Comment: @sjagr thanks! I know the have a new Open API but works only for their new Application and i am using Classic app so they suggest to me to Classic API

Comment: Please do `var_dump($tableId); var_dump($records); var_dump($tv->addRecord($tableId, $records)); die();` after you declared `$records` and add the output to your question or in a Gist/Pastebin.

Comment: @sjagr added the output. when i change mysqli_real_escape_string() to htmlspecialchars() to check it output the correct company name like `XXX's AG`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `mysqli_real_escape_string()` [returns an empty string if a MySQL connection hasn't been established](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#58650). Since you are using an external API for record management I suspect a MySQL connection never existed in the first place.

As a result, you are sending bad data to the Trackvia API - which returns a `NULL` response.

The solution is to use a non-MySQL library to parse/sanitize data into your API. I would suggest `str_replace` for the characters that your API has issues with as they come.

`htmlspecialchars` doesn't work because, with `ENT_QUOTES`, characters like `'` will become `&#39;` and `"` will become `&quot;`. You think it works correctly when you `var_dump` it because the HTML entity gets rendered back to the quote. So `XXX's AG` actually is being stored as `XXX&#39;s AG`

Comment: Thanks! is this correct? str_replace(''', '', $tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name'])?

Comment: @Hulu Did you try just leaving `$tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name']` alone? And I don't know what escaping strategy Trackvia looks for. It's very unwidely supported. `str_replace(''', '', $tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name'])` is wrong. If it's a regular convention of a \ escape, use `str_replace("'", "\\'", $tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name'])`

Comment: `var_dump($tableId)`, `var_dump($records)`, `var_dump($this->api(...))`: output works in (`$tmpArray['Customer_Bill_Name']`,`htmlspecialchars`, `Mysqli_` cases but i doesn't add the record to the table. as i have mentioned in the question Inorder to add the record in to Trackvia You need to have the exact match record for the LINKED fields

Comment: @Hulu Sorry - there's not enough information about the environment and documentation on Trackvia is minimal. This conversation should probably be saved for Trackvia support and a paid developer.